# Keep variables when casting

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to cast some long data into wide, but can't figure out how to keep certain variables attached to a unique id.  The following does what I need it to do except for it drops the lat and long variables, which are attached to each gridNumber.  I'd like to keep those when going to wide.

dput:

```
df <- structure(list(gridNumber = c("17578", "18982", "18983", "18984", 
"18985", "18986", "18987", "18988", "18989", "18990"), value = c(22.7000007629395, 
22.2900009155273, 22.25, 21.9799995422363, 21.1000003814697, 
20.7700004577637, 20.6200008392334, 20.5699996948242, 20.5699996948242, 
20.5799999237061), lat = c(-95.1249999994964, -95.1666666661633, 
-95.1249999994964, -95.0833333328295, -95.0416666661626, -94.9999999994957, 
-94.9583333328288, -94.9166666661619, -94.874999999495, -94.8333333328281
), long = c(49.4166666666667, 49.375, 49.375, 49.375, 49.375, 
49.375, 49.375, 49.375, 49.375, 49.375), ID = c("PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", 
"PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", 
"PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", 
"PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", 
"PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", "PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil", 
"PRISM_ppt_stable_4kmM2_190001_bil")), .Names = c("gridNumber", 
"value", "lat", "long", "ID"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)
wide <- dcast.data.table(df, gridNumber~ID, value = 'value')
```

Comment: No need for ".data.table". Just 'dcast' is sufficient from v1.9.6+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To explain @Frank comment (and correct answer), the cast formula takes the form `LHS ~ RHS`. `LHS` are the set of columns that you want to be the row key and similarly for columns in `RHS`. So if you want to keep gridNumber, lat and long as the unique key for each of your rows, then set `LHS` to `gridNumber + lat + long` like so:

```
wide <- dcast.data.table(df, gridNumber + lat + long ~ ID, value = 'value')
```

`dcast` can be used in place of `dcast.data.table`, as pointed out by @Arun (for any version >= 1.9.6, currently on CRAN).

Comment: Yup that did it.  Thanks to @Frank as well.